# statusBar compose multiplatform color

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

[image]

I want to change the statusBar opacity am working on CommonMain

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that you have to write code natively edge-to-edge by using `enableEdgeToEdge()` in your activity, then handle necessary paddings in your screens using `.systemBarsPadding()` in your modifier and in iOS also you need `ignoreSafeArea`.